# What is the gradle way to filter a subset of files in src/main/webapp?

Tags: war, gradle

I'm doing a maven conversion to gradle and want to see the opinions on the best way to perform the following. I currently have multiple files under src/main/webapp. Some need filtered one way and some need filtered in another.

Notionally under src/main/webapp I have a directory foo containing html and binaries and under webapp many other files including html. I want to filter just the foo/*.html files.

In my notional build.gradle I can either do:

```
war {
  eachFile {
    if(shouldFilter(it)) {
      it.filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [key: 'value'])
    }
  }
}

def shouldFilter(input) {
  input.path.contains('foo') && input.name.endsWith('.html')
}
```

or move each subset into its own directory that is not copied by default

```
war {
  from('src/main/foo-pre-filter') {
    into 'foo'
    include '*.html'
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [key: 'value'])
  }
}
```

Or is there another option I missed?

Comment: What are the different types of filters you need to do? I would use the first block, and remove the if and let gradle run the filter over all the files

Comment: Thanks.  Your first option worked great for me.

Answer (score 17):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use filesMatching.  Also, I would do it as part of the processResources task, as opposed to the war task.  It would look something like this:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('foo/*.html') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [key: 'value'])
    }
}
```

I realize the initial question was asked 2 years ago, so this probably won't help the asker, but perhaps it could help someone else in the future.

Comment: Note that you have to import `ReplaceTokens`, e.g., `import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens`

Comment: This answer works for files in `src/main/resources` but not for files in `src/main/webapp` as explicitly asked in the title of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same question today and couldn't find specific, working example right away from any of the results from Google search, one of the results led me here. After some tries, I finally get it works. Below is a working task:

```
war {
  filesMatching("**/foo/*.html") {
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [key: 'value'])
  }
}
```

Link: [filesmatching](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:filesMatching(java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action))