# How to run multiple filters on various file types in processResources

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to do some processing on some source before moving it to the build directory. Specifically, for files with a .template name, replace instances of `@timestamp@` with the `timeStamp` variable i've defined. Additionally, for .jsp files, I would like to remove whitespace between tags.

The first part of this, replacing the timestamp works. Replacing the whitespace in the jsps does not.

```
processResources {
    def timeStamp = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis())
    from ('../src/resources/webapp') {
        include '**/*.template'
        filter {
            it.replace('@timestamp@', timeStamp)
        }
        rename '(.*)\\.template', '$1'
    }
    from ('../src/resources/webapp') {
        include '**/*.jsp'
        filter {
            it.replace('>\\s+<', '><')
        }
    }
}
```

Previous to using `processResources`, I had done something like this for the minification:

```
task minifyJSPs(type: Copy) {
    from ('../src/resources/webapp') {
        include '**/*.jsp'
        filter {
            it.replace('>\\s+<', '><')
        }
    }
    into 'gbuild'
}
```

Filtering the files like this using copy worked, however, I noticed I wasn't able to copy from a location to itself -- the file would end up empty. This meant that I had to copy files from one intermediate directory to another, applying a filter at each step.

I want to be able to apply various transformations to my source in one step. How can I fix my `processResources` task?

Comment: Use `eachFile` to print the file being processed and debug the task. Maybe `-i` or `-d` switch can help as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the gradle way to filter a subset of files in src/main/webapp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608615/what-is-the-gradle-way-to-filter-a-subset-of-files-in-src-main-webapp)